# jqplot bar chart date category formated xaxis

Tags: javascript, date, graph, axis, jqplot

```
axes: { 
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    label: 'Date',
    ticks: myTicks,
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions: {
        angle: -30}
    }
}
```

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAY2c.jpg)

I need a normal formatted xaxis, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TviUK.jpg)